# Sane Sharepoint 2007 URLs

Tags: iis, sharepoint, url

In the current setup, the shared documents section has extremely convoluted URLs that are <strike>hard</strike>impossible to remember, such as the following:

```
http://example.org:8888/SharePoint/Shared%20Documents/Forms/name-num-version.aspx?RootFolder=%2fSharePoint%2fShared%20Documents%2fSW%20%2d%20Software&FolderCTID=0x01200045DC2632DDBDA14A9D4EC52D50D92391&View=%7b67A88CE2%2d8B5D%2d491D%2dB82B%2d3E3D8CE28A5D%7d
```

What I would like this example to be is something like:

```
http://example.org:8888/SharePoint/Shared-Documents/SW-Software
```

All I've done is removed the %xyz sequences from the display name with a single dash each, and the name of the view (at least for the default case). Is this possible within Sharepoint/IIS?

**FOLLOWUP**: So, manual folder cleanup works, but is there a way that Sharepoint can help me generate the cleaned up version? What about if I want to link to a file (my best guess didn't work)? I think the 'View Properties" page makes the most sense to link to, if there's a choice.

**EDIT**: I just got an automated email that gave me a 'canonical' URL to a document. It was exactly as suggested below, but with spaces (%20) replaced by '+'. Still have the question about how to easily obtain this, though (and link the the properties page).

(meta, respond in comments: should my followup be a new question on SF?)

Comment: What are you linking to exactly?  On our WSS site, if I change to a specific view, my link becomes: http://example.org/sitename/Shared%20Documents/Forms/Test%20View.aspx.  The %20 is only there because there are spaces in the names (you can rename your folders so that they don't have spaces).

Comment: It's just a folder, and the %20 and %2d are spaces and dashes, but I'd prefer that users see spaces within Sharepoint but underscores or dashes in the URL, which is what my original question was aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first create your DocumentLibrarys or folders etc do not use spaces, dashes etc. in the names. This will then create the said item with an internal name that does not have spaces etc. and this internal name is used in the forming of the url. Once you have created the item, you can go back and rename it to have spaces, dashes etc so it will now be displayed as you want but the url will still use the original internal name the item was created with which means you will not have an encoded url full of special characters.

Comment: If the items are being created programmatically the InternalName and DisplayName properties should be set accordingly to get this effect (no rename required)

Answer (score 3):

You can rename the folders, but usually Sharepoint redirects the URL to point to a view, which is why you get the long query string. If you want to go to a specific folder, you can supply it with your simplified URL (e.g. "http://server/site/shared documents/sw/software"). Your browser will take care of URL-encoding the spaces and Sharepoint will rewrite the rest of the URL.

Having said that, if you're sending a link to a folder to a colleague, you'll need to clean up first.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the folder liek so as well:

http://example.org:8888/SharePoint/LISTNAME/FOLDERNAME/SUBFOLDERNAME

SharePoint will translate these urls to the "convoluted" one on it's own.